# JSONP call to local webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, sinatra, jsonp

I have a simple sinatra webservice running on localhost:4567. The service returns some JSON an is illustrated below...

```
require 'rubygems';  
require 'sinatra'; 
require 'json';

get '/example' do
  content_type :json
  { :key1 => 'value1', :key2 => 'value2' }.to_json
end
```

I can open my browser and request "http: //localhost:4567/example" and get the json data back "{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}".

I need to make a simple ajax request with code like this ...

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://localhost:4567/example",  
    function (data) {  
        alert(data);  
    });
```

But am running into Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues. I would like to use JSONP like this...

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://localhost:4567/example/?callback=?",  
    function (data) {  
        alert(data);  
    });
```

But keep betting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ". I believe this to be the colon before my localhost port. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the request is being made off of the same URL, including port, you'll have that issue.

For JSONP, you'll want to set up your Sinatra route like so:

```
get '/example' do
  callback = params[:callback]
  json = { :key1 => 'value1', :key2 => 'value2' }.to_json

  if callback
    content_type :js
    response = "#{callback}(#{json})" 
  else
    content_type :json
    response = json
  end
  response
end
```

When making JSONP calls I personally prefer the verboseness of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:4567/example',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

The above example is almost verbatim from [this snippet](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/445-how-to-create-a-jsonp-cross-domain-webservice-with-sinatra-and-ruby).

Good Luck!